# Why does thunderbird inform that I get 3 new messages when I only get 1

Tags: email

That happens only when receiving messages from Stack Exchange, and what's the reason I didn't have Stack Exchange account anymore though I just created it yesterday, I had to create it again and again thunderbird started to inform that I got 3 new messages when clearly I got only 1. Something messed up at the Stack Exchange ?

Answer (score 0):

Thunderbird also informs you about messages that are filtered out by your spam blocker and go directly in the trash. You may get 3 messages but see only 1 in the inbox folder